# Keyboard keys working incorrectly when using Turbo C++

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, repair, c++, ide

I use turbo c++ in my laptop (32-bit, Windows 7). It used to work well. But some time back I don't know what happened but the functions of some keyboard keys seem to have messed up.

And no, there isn't any problem with my keyboard since all the keys work perfectly well when doing anything *apart from when using* (i.e., writing coding, saving file, anything..) *Turbo C++*.

DETAILS:

When I press <kbd>[</kbd> I get nothing,
using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> also does nothing.
 When I press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> or <kbd>]</kbd>
I get `]` though I should've gotten `}`. 
When I press <kbd>'</kbd> (single quote) or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>'</kbd>
I get nothing; I should've gotten `'` and `"` respectively.
Similarly, I don't get these symbols `>` `<` `?` `:`

But wait there's another shift key on the keyboard.
Pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> yields `{` though it should be `}`.
Pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> yields `}` though it should be `|`.
I do get `:` `>` and `<`, though, using this shift key.

The caps lock key also doesn't work as it should. If I have 'caps' on I have to press twice to get the 'smalls' and then again twice to get caps.

I think I may have pressed some keys accidentally but if so, I have no idea which.

I tried troubleshooting but it didn't work.
 I uninstalled Turbo C++ and then downloaded and installed it again but nothing changed.

I tried searching on the net too and the closest I think I got to is something called "keyboard layout" but I didn't anything useful for my specific problem online.

*So*, I've asked this question.
 Can somebody tell me what could have happened, and how to fix it?

Could it have happened from me pressing some combinations of keys accidentally (I am quite sure that I didn't select something from a menu whose purpose I had no idea of), i.e., is it some functionality of Turbo C++ which I am not aware of or what?

EDIT: Some relevant details:

(1) The only keyboard layout I have installed: English (United States) - US **;**

(2)(a)Language for non-Unicode programs: English (United States) **;**
      (b) Default Input language for all input fields- English (United States) - US
So, the keyboard layout matches the Language pack I'm using, correct?

(3) It matches the layout of the physical keyboard I'm using.

**Also**, I forgot to mention this but note that there wasn't any problem with Turbo C++ in the beginning, i.e. when I first downloaded it all the keyboard keys worked totally fine even while using the IDE; only later on this happened, even though I didn't change/update the IDE or keyboard layout, etc.

EDIT: *Screenshot of keyboard layout and input language & installed service*-

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the edit @G-man. The question looks beautiful now! : )

Comment: Hi! Any suggestions, guys (or gals) ?

Comment: Sounds like you have a different keyboard **layout** installed.  You have not supplied any information that would identify if that was the case.  **You have to give us longer then an hour to help you.**  Submitting a comment does update your place on the first page, only significant substantial updates to your question, will actually make that happen.  Do not abuse the edit system, only make substantial meaningful updates, otherwise the system will flag the behavior.

Comment: @Ramhound, sorry I didn't understand. Different keyboard?

Comment: In other words, what keyboard layout is Windows 7 using, update your question and be specific.  Provide a screenshot.  Meaningful relevant information only please.

Comment: **You have to give us longer then an hour to help you.** Alright, Sorry! ;) It's just that I've seen that in general if one doesn't get answers when the question's just a few minutes in then there's quite a chance he won't be getting *many* afterwards!

Comment: I have answered questions after several days, because it took me that long, to research the answer.  Even if that was the case, attempting to bump your question to the first page, isn't going to result in an answer it likely will just draw downvotes.  Most questions I see that don't get answered is because of the quality of the question, not because its not on the first page.  You shouldn't expect your answer to be answered in an hour.  Your question is going to be difficult to answer.

Comment: @Ramhound, the layout is English (United States) - US. I don't know which screenshot you were talking about, would you clarify?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68771/discussion-between-mr-reality-and-ramhound).